# how to use iimPlay() in js file using Firefox Extension(free)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, imacros

I have created .js file by renaming current.iim(Recorded macro) to current.js in Imacro Firefox extension(Free Version). I run the file by clicking on play macro but getting error as

```
SyntaxError: can not parse macro line 1: iimPlay("Open6Tabs.iim");
```

Current.js having this code where Open6Tabs.iim is in Demo-Firefox folder
iimPlay("Open6Tabs.iim");

Actual result:

```
SyntaxError: can not parse macro line 1: iimPlay("Open6Tabs.iim");"
```

Expected result: It should run successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Expected result: It should run successfully":
Yeah, nice try @OP, you could better react and follow up...

=> Read my (1st) Reply to your previous Qt again..., I already gave you the Answer...!:
=> You need to mention your FCI (Full Config Info), like I've already asked you... "Firefox Extension(free)" is not enough... => Exact Version...? + exact Version for Browser...? + OS...?

OK, finally got your FCI, after 6 days, from your parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum:

```
Firefox Quantum 68.0.2(32 bit)
Imacro version :10.0.2.1450
Windows 10
```

(... with 3 Typos in "iMacros"...)

Yeah well, then the Answer/Explanation to your "Issue" is simply documented in the Release Notes for v10.0.2 for FF...! :idea:
https://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox#Version_History

> The built-in Javascript scripting interface for playing .js files is
>   no longer available.

- I gave some Alternatives in my Answer on the iMacros Forum for using '.js' Scripts with iMacros in 2019...:
  https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=20237&p=83217#p83217

Trouble finding your previous Thread/Qt...?:
[Imacro Firefox extension call another macro using js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57569513/3799241)

(Got closed because no Follow-up from you + Low Quality + "Off-Topic".... I didn't agree with the "Off-Topic" but I couldn't do much about it as you didn't follow up yourself...)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree, it will be too complicated for any novice user.If i don't get any reply on the forum, how can you expect me to follow up in the forum as this is my first question on the forum itself. Being called a Joke, better to help in a responsible way. You want me to correct the question and that is not the answer. Anyway, this forum(you) won't help others as you will only help who are in expert.

Comment: Yeah OK, good-good, I had not realized you had also posted on the iMacros Forum, as you posted in some existing Thread from 5 years ago... https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=20237&p=83215#p83215 - And sorry for being a bit "harsh", but you didn't follow up at all on your 1st Thread... - Let's handle your Thread/Qt on the iMacros Forum, and I'll update my "Answer" here later on...

Comment: Oh...!!, and some very good News (for me, ah-ah...!), posting Comments was broken for several months on this Site, from my Default/Prod Browser (PM v26.3.3), and I just realize that it now works again... Good, they've finally fixed it..., after 6 months maybe...!